# About the variance of stochastic processes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose you go to a casino and play a gambling game, you start with 0 net worth (you are allowed to have negative net worth), each time you either win 1 or loose 1, both with the probability of $1/2$. Then after some time $t$, the ensemble standard deviation of your wealth $\sigma_t \propto \sqrt{t}$.

Now the casino introduces a stablising mechanism. When you have a higher net worth, your chance of winning the next game becomes lower, and when you have a lower net worth, your chance of winning the next game becomes higher. (but still a fair game) The question is, in this case, how would $\sigma_t$ grow as $t$ grows?

Some example of stabilising function would be: $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{x}}$,$f(x)=1/2-\lambda sgn(x)$

I have done some experiment, seems $\sigma_t \propto 1$.

Comment: When you say "still a fair game," you mean that the expected value of the game is always $0$, right?  So if you change the probability of winning, you have to change the payoffs.  How does that work?  Do you just increase/decrease the amount you can win, the amount you can lose, or both?  If both, how much do you adjust each one?

Comment: Fair game means, starting with 0 net worth, the expected net worth at any t is 0. the payoffs of each round is not changed. The game as a whole is fair, but each individual round need not to be fair.